# Getting wrong location on GPS in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gps, location

Tried different methods using core location frame work in iOS but not getting exact location through GPS. Even the apple maps & google maps are not pointing to correct location. See the code snippet I'm using:

> MyLocation class header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MyLocation : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

> MyLocation class m file

```
  #import "MyLocation.h"
    #import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
    #import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

    @implementation MyLocation

    @synthesize curLocation;

    -(id)init{

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0;

    //locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    //locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [self updateLocation];

    curLocation = CGPointZero;
    return self;

    }

    -(void)updateLocation{

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {




    curLocation  = CGPointMake( newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    }
```

Comment: If both Apple Maps & Google Maps show wrong location then I'd guess your application will as well. But if you want to be super percise you shouldn't use kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters. Use kCLLocationAccuracyBest or kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation, but those will use more battery. In general GPS is accurate enough, but not very accurate.

Comment: please test it on device

Comment: i am also facing this problem. i had tried with kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation also but not getting success .  and i had tested this on multiple devices , sometimes it gets accurate result but mostly not accurate.

Comment: Check my reply elsewhere in this thread.  I just ran into this over the past few days.  It's not you.  It's the device.

Comment: Hi @Brave Heart Have you fixed this issue. I am facing same issue. But I am unable to fix it. Can you please help me if you have fixed this issue.Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As krzy says, if Apple Maps is giving the same types of results, you are dealing with the limitations of the GPS on your phone. (Which isn't very good.)

A couple of things you can do to get better results:

When you first ask the location manager for location updates, the first update you get is usually a "stale" reading from the last time the GPS was active. It can be hours, days, or weeks old. Check the timestamp and discard readings that are more than a few seconds old.

Next, check the horizontal accuracy on the readings you get. "Accuracy" would be better named "slop" or "circle of confusion". Your actual location can be anywhere in a circle with that radius. High "accuracy" readings mean the reading is not very accurate. You probably want to discard readings with an accuracy reading > 100 meters.

Comment: Not really, no. Why don't you try to figure out what I described? This is pretty straightforward stuff.

Comment: Providing code for straightforward suggestions can be counterproductive, because then the reader simply copy and pastes the code rather than learning the APIs well enough to write the code him/herself.

Comment: Yeah true that users sometimes just copy and paste the code instead of trying to learn the API.

Answer (score 2):

If your "curLocation" is an instance of CLLocation you should initialize it this way

```
curLocation =  [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:yourLatitude longitude:yourLongitude];
```

and not with CGPointMake

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the method you are using `didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` has been deprecated since iOS6. You'll want to be using the `didUpdateLocations:` method instead as shown below.

Secondly, you don't need to create a new location or coordinate object in the way you are doing it.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
}
```

This function returns:

> *An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data. This
>   array always contains at least one object representing the current
>   location. If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived
>   before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional
>   entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which
>   they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the
>   end of the array.* (Apple docs)

Regarding the accuracy, there's not much you can do to improve the accuracy other than continue updating locations and hope for the horizontalAccuracy property of future updates to improve. Setting the best accuracy and no distance filter may help.

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem under iOS 8 and an iPhone 6, but on other devices under iOS 7 and iOS 6, there was no problem reporting location.

It ended up not being my code, buuut…

Apple Maps suddenly thought my device was 200 miles away in NYC.  All this time I thought the issue was with iOS 8, but for some reason, Location Services and/or Privacy settings or the underlying hardware placed the device in NYC.

We reset Location Services and Privacy on the device and in a few minutes, CoreLocation started properly returning the device's proper GPS coordinates and updating it on a regular basis.

**AHA!!**  Within the app's scheme, I had set Core Location to Simulate Locations and had selected NYC for both the scheme for running the app in the Simulator and on the device.  When run on the device just once and still in the background, this set the location to be NYC for all the apps using location services and geofencing region monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]
```